# Windows Share: gvfs mounts it correctly, mount.cifs not

Tags: 14.04, mount, samba, cifs, gvfs

I've since some days a strange problem with Ubuntu 14.04LTS trusty and a Windows Share.. It could be mounted correctly until some days ago:

With gvfs my share is mounted correctly:

```
gvfs-mount smb://[MyDomain]/centren/
```

If I try to mount it for every user with mount.cifs:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credential=/root/.smbcred,vers=1.0,rw,uid=1009,hard,nosetuids,noperm,sec=ntlm //[MyDomain]/centren /media/S
```

then I have some permission problem:

```
ls -la /run/user/1009/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=[MyDomain]\,share\=centren/AG/[MyAG]
insgesamt 200
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser   4096 Jan  8  2016 .
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser 196608 Feb  5 13:49 ..
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser   4096 Jan 30 11:58 mydir

ls -la /media/S/AG/[MyAG]
ls: Öffnen von Verzeichnis /media/S/AG/[MyAG] nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
```

if it can help:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
uname -r
3.19.0-80-generic
mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself.
At the end there was some problem/bug with the kernel. I've updated to kernel 4 and everything worked again!

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o credential=/root/.smbcred,vers=1.0,rw,uid=1009,hard,nosetuids,noperm,sec=ntlm //[MyDomain]/centren /media/S
[sudo] password for myuser: 
$ ls -la /media/S/AG/[MyAG]
insgesamt 196
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser   4096 Jan  8  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 196608 Feb  9 15:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser      0 Feb 12 10:03 MyDir
$ uname -r
4.4.0-98-generic
$ mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.0
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```